# Multiple joins to same association with different aliases in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I am building a messaging system for my web application using Spring MVC with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as my JPA provider.

I have five entities: `Thread`, `ThreadParticipant`, `Participant`, `Account` and `Company`. Each message thread has at least two participants, one of which is associated with a user (`Account` entity), and the other is associated with a `Company`. This constraint is enforced by the application. The database is designed like this to support future features. An example of two participants for a given thread in the database looks as follows:

```
id      account_id      company_id
1       44              NULL
2       NULL            123
```

The row with id=1 is the user, and the row with id=2 is the company. What I want to do is to write an HQL query that extracts all `Thread` objects for a given account, containing both the user/account participant as well as the company participant. I have tried to use different alias for my joins, like this:

```
select distinct t
from Thread t
inner join fetch t.threadParticipants user_tp
inner join fetch t.threadParticipants company_tp
inner join fetch user_tp.participant user_p
inner join fetch user_p.account a
inner join fetch company_tp.participant receiver_p
inner join fetch receiver_p.company
where a.id = :accountId
```

I get the exception `cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags` due to the two fetches of `t.threadParticipants`. If I only do a single join here, the generated SQL simply ignores my additional join and only joins to `Participant` once, which requires a participant to have both an account and a company associated. With raw SQL, I can do like this, and it works fine:

```
select *
from thread t
inner join thread_participant user_tp on (user_tp.thread_id = t.id)
inner join thread_participant company_tp on (company_tp.thread_id = t.id)
inner join participant user_p on (user_p.id = user_tp.participant_id)
inner join account a on (a.id = user_p.account_id)
inner join participant company_p on (company_p.id = company_tp.participant_id)
inner join company c on (c.id = company_p.company_id)
where a.id = 123;
```

If I don't use different alias for the same table (see the below query), the query runs fine, but I only get one of the thread participants returned - the one that is associated with the account.

```
select distinct t
from Thread t
inner join fetch t.threadParticipants tp
inner join fetch tp.participant p
inner join fetch p.account a
left join fetch p.company
where a.id = :accountId
```

Is there any way that I can do what I am trying to do with HQL, or do I have to go with using native SQL?

My mapping is as follows:

**Thread entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thread")
public class Thread {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "thread", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Collection<ThreadParticipant> threadParticipants = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Participant entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "participant")
public class Participant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, targetEntity = Account.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, targetEntity = Company.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**ThreadParticipant entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thread_participant")
@IdClass(ThreadParticipantPK.class)
public class ThreadParticipant implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Participant.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "participant_id")
    private Participant participant;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Thread.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id")
    private Thread thread;

    @Column(name = "last_viewed", nullable = true)
    private Date lastViewed;


    // Getters and setters
}
```

**ThreadParticipantPK**

```
public class ThreadParticipantPK implements Serializable {
    private Thread thread;
    private Participant participant;

    public ThreadParticipantPK() { }

    public ThreadParticipantPK(Thread thread, Participant participant) {
        this.thread = thread;
        this.participant = participant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ThreadParticipantPK)) return false;

        ThreadParticipantPK that = (ThreadParticipantPK) o;

        if (!participant.equals(that.participant)) return false;
        if (!thread.equals(that.thread)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = thread.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + participant.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the type of the `threadParticipants` collection to `Set` instead of a `Collection`:

```
private Set<ThreadParticipant> threadParticipants;
```